# golang regexp replace single digits

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to replace single digits, only if they are not accompanied by a word character. For e.g.

`[*:*:1] a2b*d 3n 4q test 5 test 6`

Should be change into

`[*:*:*] a2b*d 3n 4q test * test *`

In the above list, the numbers 1, 5 and 6 have been replaced with *, but 2, 3 and 4 are not replaced as they are accompanied by a word character.

The below code works, but partially

https://play.golang.org/p/OC6bk4PLyq

```
s := "[*:*:1] a2b*d 3n 4q test 5 test 6"
re := regexp.MustCompile("[^0-9A-Za-z_][0-9]+[^0-9A-Za-z_]")
s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "*")
fmt.Println(s) // Prints - [*:** a2b*d 3n 4q test*test 6
```

Here, I would like the `:` and the `]` in the first word to be retained and the spaces around `5` to be retained. Also the `6` is not replaced.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved in Go.

Comment: Can there be `3.5` like values? What is the expected behavior? Preserve `3.5`?

Comment: Great that you asked this. 3.5 should be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
([^\w.]|^)[0-9]([^\w.]|\.(?:\D|$)|$)
```

And replace with `$1*$2` replacement pattern.

**Details**:

- `([^\w.]|^)` - Group 1: a char that is not a dot or a word char (`\w` = `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) or start of string (`^`)
- `[0-9]` - 1 digit
- `([^\w.]|\.(?:\D|$)|$)` - Group 2: a char other than a dot or a word char (`[^\w.]`), or a `.` followed with a non-digit or end of string (`\.(?:\D|$)`)  or end of string (`$`)

The `$1` in the replacement pattern re-inserts the Group 1 contents into the result, and `$2` does the same with Group 2 contents.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xzghYw/4) and a [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/lsaEEsnbqG):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := "[*:*:1] a2b*d 3.5 5, 7. 3n 4q test 5 test 6"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`([^\w.]|^)[0-9]([^\w.]|\.(?:\D|$)|$)`)
    s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1*$2")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

**UPDATE**: To also remove 1-digit integer numbers that are separated with 1 char, use a loop to check if a match still occurs, and replace until no match. Replace `s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1*$2")` with:

```
for re.MatchString(s)  {
    s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1*$2")
}
```

See [this Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/wa9avOg1zA).

Comment: I updated to make sure only 1 standalone digits are replaced, all cases of `3.5` are now handled correctly.

Comment: Here `3-5` does not work correctly. It replaces like `*-5`. But it should be `3-5`

Comment: I added the fix for that. That happens because of the overlapping matches. A check with the same regex should be implemented. While there is a match, proceed with replacements. This is the only workaround I can think of since Go regex does not support even lookaheads.

Answer (score 2):

The regex `\b\d+\b` will solve your problem. Following is the go code.

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\b\d+\b`)
    var str = `[*:*:1] a2b56d 3n 4q test 5 test 877565656`
    var substitution = `*`

    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(str, substitution))
}
```

You can test this regex at https://regex101.com/r/cyCS9C/2

Comment: This also works, except the 3.5 part is not preserved.

Comment: @FizerKhan: It is  a common problem to match single digits (or just ints) with a regex avoiding matching parts of float values. The usual workaround is by added `(?<!\.)` lookbehind and `(?!\.\d)` lookahead, but Go does not support lookarounds. See my answer for a work around.

Comment: @Wiktor Got it. I don't know about go support.  I thought he wants to replace all digits(both integers or floats) to "*".

Comment: Yeah, I see. (note I meant *Go **regex** does not support lookarounds.*)